# Ruby: Use the return of the conditional for variable assignment and comparison

Tags: ruby, ruby-block

I have a method and in order to check whether it is being passed a block, I do the following:

```
if block_given?
    res = yield(array[i], array[i+1])
  else
    res = array[i] - array[i+1]
  end
```

However RuboCop is giving me a warning which I don't really understand in the `if block_given?` line:

> Use the return of the conditional for variable assignment and comparison

Is there any other more rubyist way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 76, accepted):

What the warning is telling you to do is:

```
res = if block_given?
        yield(array[i], array[i+1])
      else
        array[i] - array[i+1]
      end
```

That is, having a single assignment instead of two (or even more).

Comment: maybe `res = block_given? ? yield(array[i], array[i + 1]) : array[i] - array[i + 1]` would be valid too?

Comment: Sure, but this one seems to be more readable. Specially if there are multiple branches (think of nesting `? :`).

Comment: also, alignment is important for Rubocop.

Comment: noloman, yes, and I think that’s preferable. The [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) favours the use of ternery expressions, provided (as here) there is only one expression per branch and those expressions are not themselves terneries. I agree.

Comment: just watch out to Rubocop indentation rules. Depending on your setup, else and end must be aligned to `res` and not to `if`